Tool dialog popup has disappeared
I am working on a blender model that, at some point, has failed to display any popup dialogs associated with tools .
For example, using the Bisect tool in mesh, I would expect the bisect options to appear in a popup at the left bottom of the screen. Similarly, in Clean Up>Merge By Distance, when vertices are selected and this clicked, I would expect the dialog to adjust the difference. All tools are failing to work in this way. No dialog boxes appear.
If I open a new blender project, all is working fine. So something has occurred in my specific project to stop the dialog boxes. Any ideas?

Are you sure it’s not just minimized?
